# Edges of display are crisp but middle is blurry.

Tags: windows-8

I've been using my tv as a monitor for some time. As a display it was working well could watch netflix and play most games. Some would not start and say invalid format but I'm not worried about that issue my main issue is just today the middle part of my display is blurry, the edges still look great but the middle is very difficult to read. I've tried adjusting the screen resolution but to no avail. Looking for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

One likely reason is [overscan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overscan), or possibly just regular mismatch with the TV's native resolution. Try opening [this](http://www.techmind.org/lcd/phasing.html) or [this](http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/sharpness.php) test page to determine whether it's the case.

For historical reasons dating to the *earliest* analog sets, the transmitted picture used to be larger than the viewing are. Nowadays, even most digital TVs expect to be receiving such oversized input and therefore stretch the input picture to be slightly larger than the viewing area even if it'd normally be the exact size, so the edges are cut off and the rest is somewhat blurry. Unfortunately this is applied even to HDMI input. Most TVs have a way of disabling overscan, but hidden under all sorts of different marketing names; you'll have to search the web for your specific model.

- Matthew Garrett: [TVs are all awful](http://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/8705.html)